# An external usb storage device auto-mounts with root permissions

Tags: usb, permissions, automount, filemanager

I usually have no problems using USB sticks etc. with my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This time, when I inserted my 1 TB Seagate storage device, it showed up in the file explorer, but I was not able to copy any files to it. I saw in the properties that the device is mounted with root permissions. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, all USB drives, once mounted, are in the `/media` directory

```
cp /media/your-usb/file-in-usb ~
```

That copies a file on your USB disk to the user's home directory, assuming the drive is called `your-usb` and the file is `file-in-usb.`

Comment: This is not answering the question asked. I need to copy *to* the drive, not from it. However, I do not have writing permissions.

Comment: try to change ownership          sudo chown root:root /path to your drive

Comment: What's  root:root? Where in this command do I specify the user name?

Comment: yes first root is for username and second for group, this command will change the ownership.

Comment: But I need to give ownership to the regular user, not to root!

Comment: with root user you can access full privileges, but if you want, you can change it according your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But I want to solve the problem once and for all instead of having to issue this command every time.